# Airport synchronization - threads stuck

Tags: java, multithreading, conditional-statements

I wanted to code the airport monitor (planes trying to arrive, planes trying to departure, etc.) and I have a problem with something. Only one thread seems to be working, others are stuck somewhere. Can somebody please look at this code and help?

```
public class Lotniskowiec {

public int K=5;
public int N = 10;

final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
final Condition toStart  = lock.newCondition(); 
final Condition toLand= lock.newCondition(); 
 boolean wantsToStart;
 boolean wantsToLand;
 int atAirport= 0;
boolean free= true;

private  void free_landing_area(){

        lock.lock();
    if(atAirport< K){
        if(wantsToLand){
            toLand.signal();
        }else toStart.signal();
    }
    else{
        if(wantsToStart){
        toStart.signal();
        } else if (atAirport< N){
            toLand.signal();
        }
    }       
        lock.unlock();
}

public  void wants_to_start(){

    lock.lock();
    if(!free){
        lock.unlock();
        try {
            toStart.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    lock.lock();
    free=false;
    lock.unlock();


}

public void started(){

    lock.lock();
    atAirport-=1;
    free=true;

    free_landing_area();
    lock.unlock();

}

public void wants_to_land(){

        lock.lock();
    if(!free|| atAirport==N){
        lock.unlock();
        try {
            toLand.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    lock.lock();
    free=false;
    lock.unlock();
}

public void landed(){

    lock.lock();
    atAirport+=1;
    free=true;

    free_landing_area();
    lock.unlock();  
}
}
```

So sorry for names of variables ;)

threads:

```
public class Samolot implements Runnable{

Random random = new Random();
    Lotniskowiec lotniskowiec = new Lotniskowiec();
int id;

public Samolot(int id, Lotniskowiec lotniskowiec){
    this.id=id;
            this.lotniskowiec=lotniskowiec;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
          try {
              Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
              Lotniskowiec.wants_to_land();
              System.out.println(id + " chce ladowac");
              Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
              Lotniskowiec.landed();
              System.out.println(id + " wyladowal");
              Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
              Lotniskowiec.wants_to_start();
              System.out.println(id + " chce startowac");
              Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
              Lotniskowiec.started();
              System.out.println(id + " wystartowal");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
}



}
```

starting threads:

```
Samolot r = new Samolot(1,lotniskowiec);
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();
```

Comment: Please do refactor the names, without the meaning the code becomes harder to read.

Comment: Am I right thinking the code for the threads themselves is still missing?

Comment: I've added that, but I am pretty sure that the problem is in the monitor ;)

Comment: And how are you starts threads?

Comment: Added that as well ;)

Comment: You better hurry; planes are circling your airport and running low on fuel!

Comment: And the disaster happened ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `wants_to_land` and `wants_to_start` are booleans but they should be integers. Otherwise how will you be able to keep track of how many planes wish to land?

Also, I suspect it's good enough to `lock.lock()` at the start of each method called by the planes and `lock.unlock()` at the end of it. In your current code a plane can acquire the lock more times than it releases it, effectively stealing it from the others.

Also, it may help to make the lock fair.

So

```
    public static int K = 5;
    public static int N = 10;

    final static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
    final static Condition toStart = lock.newCondition();
    final static Condition toLand = lock.newCondition();
    static int wantsToStart = 0;
    static int wantsToLand = 0;
    static int atAirport = 0;
    static boolean free = true;

    private static void free_landing_area() {
        if (atAirport < K) {
            if (wantsToLand > 0) {
                toLand.signal();
            } else {
                toStart.signal();
            }
        } else {
            if (wantsToStart > 0) {
                toStart.signal();
            } else if (atAirport < N) {
                toLand.signal();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void wants_to_start() {
        lock.lock();
        if (!free) {
            try {
                wantsToStart++;
                toStart.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        free = false;
        lock.unlock();
    }

    public static void started() {
        lock.lock();
        atAirport -= 1;
        free = true;
        wantsToStart--;
        free_landing_area();
        lock.unlock();
    }

    public static void wants_to_land() {
        lock.lock();
        if (!free || atAirport == N) {
            try {
                wantsToLand++;
                toLand.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        free = false;
        lock.unlock();
    }

    public static void landed() {
        lock.lock();
        atAirport += 1;
        free = true;
        wantsToLand--;
        free_landing_area();
        lock.unlock();
    }
```

Finally, I believe you actually need to await() in a while loop, since threads may be woken accidentally in some cases.

> When waiting upon a Condition, a "spurious wakeup" is permitted to
>   occur, in general, as a concession to the underlying platform
>   semantics. This has little practical impact on most application
>   programs as a Condition should always be waited upon in a loop,
>   testing the state predicate that is being waited for.

So the code above is not quite there yet. But that was not what was keeping your threads stuck.

Comment: After repairing that all and actually changing wantsToStart and WantsToLearn - it worked. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the clue:
Other threads are locked in wants_to_land method at toLand.await() statement.
toLand.signal() never happens, because if(wantsToLand) and if(wantsToStart) are allways false (You aren't changing it nowhere).
Consider refreshing sync logic and see if that helps.